# consult-find - can't find only folders (without files)

Tags: consult

Linux Mint 20
Emacs 27.2

I want to find ONLY folders **target** (include empty)  in some folder (e.g **myProject**)

Steps:

In dired mode

```
M-x consult-find
/target
```

And here result:
[image: 1]

As you can see it found not only folders **target**. But also all files.
But I need ONLY folders **target**.
The result must be smt like this:

[image: 2]

In Linux terminal I can do this by the next command:

```
find myProject/ -type d -name "target"
```

But how I can do this by `consult-find` ?

Comment: Does `consult-find` use the Unix tool `find` underneath? If so, you can try to figure out how to pass to the underlying `find` a `-type d` option to select only directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both answers (@NickD' and the OP's) are right in that `consult-find` is running `find` and that passing `type d` to it is the way to achieve the desired effect.  But both of them suggested to create a wrapper command or configure `consult-find-args`.  However, there's actually a idiom for such things in `consult`'s asynchronous search commands (`consult-find` being one of them). You can actually pass additional command line options on the spot to the "vanilla" `consult-find` with `--`. So, you could search for `#target -- -type d` to get only directories in your search.

Answer (score 2):

I just checked and indeed `consult-find` uses `find` underneath through the variable `consult-find-args` whose default value is `find . -not ( -wholename */.* -prune )`. So try throwing in a `-type d` in there to make it `find . -type d -not ( -wholename */.* -prune )` and see if that works (I have not tested it). If it does, you can write your own function - perhaps `consult-find-dir` - that let-binds `consult-find-args` as above, before calling `consult-find`.

Comment: I added my answer

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.
From documentation:

> Consult splits the input string into two parts, if the first character
> is a punctuation character, like #.
> For example #grep-regexps#filter-string, is split at the second #. The
> string grep-regexps is passed to Grep. If you enter multiple regular
> expressions separated by space only lines matching all regular
> expressions are shown. In order to match space literally, escape the
> space with a backslash. The filter-string is passed to the fast Emacs
> filtering to further narrow down the list of matches

.

> consult-find, consult-locate: Find file by matching the path against a
> regexp. Like for =consult-grep,= either the project root or the
> current directory is the root directory for the search. The input
> string is treated similarly to consult-grep, where the first part is
> passed to find, and the second part is used for Emacs filtering.

So in my case:

#target#target$

And here result:[image]

And now its find `target` folders.

Thanks for @NickD the problem with this approach is that it also find file with name **target**.

So I use another approach. I create my custom function (change value of variable `consult-find-args`):

```
(defun consult-find-dir ()
  "Search for regexp with find only DIR in DIR with INITIAL input."
  (interactive)
  (setq consult-find-args "find . -type d -not ( -wholename */.* -prune )")
  (consult-find)
  )
```

This is better written as follows, with `consult-find-args` let-bound to the desired value:

```el
(defun consult-find-dir ()
    "Search for regexp with find only DIR in DIR with INITIAL input."
    (interactive)
    (let ((consult-find-args "find . -type d -not ( -wholename */.* -prune )"))
       (consult-find))
```

Here result:

```
M-x consult-find-dir
target#target$
```

[image]

And now it found **ONLY** folder **target**
[image]

Comment: One problem: if you have a *file* called `target`, then you cannot use this method to exclude it.

Comment: @NickD I updated my answer

Comment: ... which is what I suggested in my answer in the first place :-) There is also a `find-dired`  function that might be just what the doctor ordered: `(find-dired DIR "-type d -name target")`. See [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68753/grep-contents-of-a-set-of-files-from-find) question for details.

Comment: BTW, you don't want to `setq` the variable `consult-find-args` in your function. You want to let-bind it: `...(let ((consult-find-args "find ...")) (consult-find)))`.

Comment: @NickD I think custom function is better, because I input only directory name (target). But if I use "find-dired" I need to input more text:  "-type d -name target" :-)

Comment: It depends on how often you need the functionality: writing many functions to deal with slightly different situations does not work as well as having one function that deals with a slightly more general situation by passing a single parameter to specialize it. It's a matter of judgment.