# grep contents of a set of files from find

Tags: projectile, find-file, grep

I want to grep contents of all CMakeLists.txt files in a project (nested within a directory) so I can jump from each instance, like I would when running emacs grep function.  In the examples below I'm looking for "Boost".

I can get the results I want with the following command in bash:

```
grep Boost $(find . -name CMakeLists.txt)
```

I tried:

- in eshell calling `$grep Boost $(find . -name CmakeLists.txt)`
- calling emacs-grep with `grep --color -nH --null -e Boost $(find . -name CMakeLists.txt)`
- noodling around with projectile.

So far with no success.  Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: In the eshell and emacs-grep invocation, did you forget the `.txt` or is that a typo?

Comment: indeed, a typo.

Comment: FWIW, using emacs-grep with a similar command worked fine for me.

Comment: See also `C-h f lgrep`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, so maybe this won't help, but...

There's command `find-grep-dired`. Here's its doc from the version in [`find-dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/find-dired%2b.el):

> **`find-grep-dired`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in [`find-dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/find-dired%2b.el).
>
> It is bound to `menu-bar search find find-grep-dired`, `menu-bar subdir find find-grep-dired`.
>
> `(find-grep-dired DIR REGEXP &optional DEPTH-LIMITS EXCLUDED-PATHS)`
>
> Use Dired on the list of files in `DIR` whose contents match `REGEXP`.
>
> The `find` command run (after changing into `DIR`) is essentially this,
> where `LS-SWITCHES` is `(car find-ls-option)`:
>
> ```
> find . \( -type f -exec grep grep-program find-grep-options \
>   -e REGEXP {} \; \) LS-SWITCHES
> ```
>
> Thus `REGEXP` can also contain additional grep options.
>
> Optional arg `DEPTH-LIMITS` is a list `(MIN-DEPTH MAX-DEPTH)` of the
> minimum and maximum depths.  If `nil`, search directory tree under `DIR`.
>
> Optional arg `EXCLUDED-PATHS` is a list of strings that match paths to
> exclude from the search.  If `nil`, search all directories.
>
> When both optional args are non-`nil`, the `find` command run is this:
>
> ```
> find .
>  -mindepth MIN-DEPTH -maxdepth MAX-DEPTH
>   \( -path EXCLUDE1 -o -path EXCLUDE2 ... \)
>   -prune -o -exec grep-program find-grep-options -e REGEXP {} \;
>   LS-SWITCHES
> ```
>
> where `EXCLUDE1`, `EXCLUDE2`... are the `EXCLUDED-PATHS`, but shell-quoted.

---

There's also command `find-dired`, which is essentially a general `find` command:

> **`find-dired`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
> [`find-dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/find-dired%2b.el).
>
> `(find-dired DIR ARGS &optional DEPTH-LIMITS EXCLUDED-PATHS)`
>
> Run `find` and put its output in a buffer in Dired Mode.
>
> Then run `find-dired-hook` and `dired-after-readin-hook`.
>
> The `find` command run (after changing into `DIR`) is essentially this,
> where `LS-SWITCHES` is `(car find-ls-option)`:
>
> ```
> find . \( ARGS \) LS-SWITCHES
> ```
>
> Optional args:
>
> - `DEPTH-LIMITS`:   Minimum and maximum depths: `(MIN-DEPTH MAX-DEPTH)`.
> - `EXCLUDED-PATHS`: Strings matching paths to be excluded.
>   Uses `find` switch `-path`.
>
> When both optional args are non-`nil`, the `find` command run is this:
>
> ```
> find . -mindepth MIN-DEPTH -maxdepth MAX-DEPTH
>        \( -path EXCLUDE1 -o -path EXCLUDE2 ... \)
>        -prune -o \( ARGS \) LS-SWITCHES
> ```
>
> where `EXCLUDE1`, `EXCLUDE2`... are the `EXCLUDED-PATHS`, but shell-quoted.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the question rightly, you want <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-grep`

You would run that and then edit the template, adding the files names to search, and the pattern to grep.  The before/after would be something like this:

```
find . -type f -exec grep --color -nH --null -e  \{\} +
find . -type f -name CmakeLists.txt -exec grep --color -nH --null -e 'Boost' \{\} +
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                  ^^^^^^^
```

You would enter the grep pattern first, as Emacs puts the cursor at that position in the prompt (after the `-e`); but you can then edit the rest of the options as required.  By default, if you enter only a grep pattern, the command will search all regular files.